# ¿Como procesar un archivo txt para generar un determiando treeview en c#?

Tags: c#, windows-forms

Llevo dias intentando por mi cuenta tomar un determinado archivo txt, y que al ejecutar el programa, tome ese archivo y genere un determinado treeview **(Obvio no quiero la solucion pero si ayuda, a no ser  que sea muy complejo)**, la parte de lectura ya funciona.

Este debe ser variable, pero no consigo saber como hacer para que en este control me genere la estructuras de nodos en cuestión. Lo que tampoco encuentro y no se si sería relevante para la solución, es poder saber cuándo termina una linea para tomar la última palabra (ya que en el problema se usan asteriscos como separación, pero no al final de cada renglón) y cómo identificar si un nodo ya está para que este no repita un nodo principal, sinó que lo seleccione y pregunte si ya hay otro subnodo adentro y así, armando la estructura. Adjunto una foto de cómo me debe quedar:
Texto:

> Cordoba*Villa Maria*Barrio Lamadrid
>
> Cordoba/Villa Maria/Barrio Ameghino
>
> Cordoba/Villa Maria/Barrio Centro
>
> Cordoba/Villa Maria/Barrio Palermo
>
> Cordoba/Villa Nueva/Barrio La Reserva
>
> Cordoba/Tio Pujio
>
> Cordoba/James Craik/Barrio JC 1
>
> Cordoba/James Craik/Barrio JC 2
>
> Cordoba/Oliva
>
> Santa Fe/Rosario/Barrio C. Escalada
>
> Santa Fe/Rosario/Primero de Mayo
>
> Santa Fe/Rosario/Alberdi
>
> Santa Fe/Rafaela
>
> San Luis/Merlo
>
> Chubut/Trelew
>
> Chubut/Rawson
>
> Rio Negro/Bariloche

```
string Ruta = @"C:\Users\Tomas\Desktop\Universidad\F__ Practica profesionalizante 1\Guia de trabajos 1\Guia de trabajos 1\bin\Debug\Archivo para TreeView.txt";

StreamReader Leer = new StreamReader(Ruta);
string Auxiliar = string.Empty;
while (!Leer.EndOfStream)
{
    Auxiliar = string.Empty;
    foreach (char Asterisco in Leer.ReadLine())
    {
        if (Asterisco == '*')
        {
            txtprueba.Text += Auxiliar;
            tvwLocalidades.Nodes.Add(Auxiliar);
            Auxiliar = string.Empty;
         }
         else
         {
            Auxiliar += Asterisco;
         }
   }
   tvwLocalidades.Nodes.Add(Auxiliar);
   txtprueba.Text += Auxiliar + "\r\n";
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿No tienes un ejemplo de tus datos de entrada?

Comment: Necesitamos que la pregunta sea un poco mas especifica. Con que parte exactamente es con que estas teniendo problemas? Con el análisis del archivo de texto? Si es así, sería bueno que pusieses un ejemplo de dicho archivo, así como cualquier código relevante y que hayas usado que nos pueda dar alguna pista mas.

Comment: Perdón por los acentos. Mi entrada seria lo que esta a la derecha en forma de archivo de texto, lo leo en el evento load del formulario y trabajo con él (modifique la publicacion mostrando lo que tengo), el txtPrueba es para imprimir lo que voy separando para poder ver si leé bien el archivo. Me quede bloqueado y no sé como continuar por las dudas que puse en la publicacion, la de detectar el fin de línea y la de saber si un nodo ya existe para ir armando el arbol

Comment: Pone tu ejemplo de archivo tambien como texto. Supongo que es winforms? agrega eso tambien como tag en la pregunta.

Comment: Listo (cambie los asteriscos por barras porque el editor no me los tomaba y estaba todo junto), estoy aprendiendo todavia a publicar bien tambien.

Comment: No termino de entender exactamente cual es el problema. Pero si es dividir cada linea por los astericos, lo que debes hacer es usar algo como `var partes=Leer.ReadLine().Split('*');` De esa manera, en `partes` tienes cada una de las partes de cada fila, que puedes añadir a tu treeview

Comment: No sabe hacer cortes de control para meter todo en el arbol @Pikoh

Comment: claro, detectar nodos ya creados o no, y lo mismo adentro de cada nodo, para armar con el texto, el arbol de la foto, teniendo que ser flexible el codigo por si me cambia el TXT el profesor. Con botones y `textbox` en tiempo de ejecucion se hacerlo, pero no en codigo si no puedo seleccionar a que nodo le quiero agregar un hijo seleccionandolo y añadiendole lo que haya en un `texbox`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te dejo este ejemplo. Vamos a desmenuzarlo por partes.

Los datos se toman de un array de strings (que es lo mismo que un archivo)

```
public string[] datos = new string[]
{
    "Cordoba/Villa Maria/Barrio Lamadrid",
    "Cordoba/Villa Maria/Barrio Ameghino",
    "Cordoba/Villa Maria/Barrio Centro",
    "Cordoba/Villa Maria/Barrio Palermo",
    "Cordoba/Villa Nueva/Barrio La Reserva",
    "Cordoba/Tio Pujio",
    "Cordoba/James Craik/Barrio JC 1",
    "Cordoba/James Craik/Barrio JC 2",
    "Cordoba/Oliva",
    "Santa Fe/Rosario/Barrio C. Escalada",
    "Santa Fe/Rosario/Primero de Mayo",
    "Santa Fe/Rosario/Alberdi",
    "Santa Fe/Rafaela",
    "San Luis/Merlo",
    "Chubut/Trelew",
    "Chubut/Rawson",
    "Rio Negro/Bariloche",
};
```

Y despues podes poner esto en cualquier lado. como prueba, en un boton seria lo ideal por si tenes que revisar algo.

```
foreach (string item in datos)
{
    var Fila = item.Split('/');
    //El nodo anterior
    TreeNode node = null;
    /La clave que vamos a armar
    string key = "";
    foreach (var parte in Fila)
    {
        //Temporal para ver si existe el nodo
        TreeNode nodeE = null;
        key += parte;
        if (node == null)
        {
            //sobre la raiz
            nodeE = treeView1.Nodes[key];
        }
        else
        {
            nodeE = node.Nodes[key];
        }
        //Si hay un nodo con este nombre, sigo, si no, lo creo sobre el que viene de antes             
        if (nodeE == null)
        {
            //no encontre este
            if (node == null)
            {
                //No hay padre
                node = treeView1.Nodes.Add(key, parte);
            }
            else
            {
                node = node.Nodes.Add(key, parte);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            node = nodeE;
        }
    }
}
```

Este metodo problablemente no sea el ideal, pero lo que hace es ir revisando linea a linea, cada padre, lo busca si existe, y si no existe lo crea. Siempre se queda con el nodo anterior y busca agregar sobre ese nodo. Como clave, se usa el string, ya que se supone que es unico (habria que agregar un control de error por si el archivo tiene lineas duplicadas).

Comment: Gracias, lo voy a probar!

Comment: si me funciono! Serias tan amable de ponerme en el codigo un poco mas de detalle de como funciona asi aprendo del codigo? no me gusta copiar y pegar nada mas, te lo agradeceria enormemente